# How to communicate between Components with out flux in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Ok, I do know through `refs` communicate between parent and child or use `this.props.onClick = {this.props.onClick}`, I got stuck in situation communicate between grandparent and child like this:

Says we have some blogs, once we click a blog title, the corresponding blog content will show, so we create three components: BlogAdmin, BlogTitle and Blog (Here let's just focusing on BlogAdmin and BlogTitle)

When BlogTitle is clicked, I want to notify BlogAdmin set currentblog to specify blog. But I got stuck on how to pass the data and how to trigger the event, better with out using pubSub.

Below is my example, I removed some data get/set and grammars making it clear.

```
var BlogTitle = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return
      <li>{this.props.blog.title}</li>
  }
});

var BlogTitles = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return 
      <ul>
        {this.state.blogs.map}
          <BlogTitle blog={blog} />
  }
})

var BlogAdmin = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return 
      <BlogTitles />
      <BlogContent />
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

The easy solution is to add a callback function and send it down all the way like this:

```
var BlogTitle = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return
      <li onClick={this.handleTitleClick}>{this.props.blog.title}</li>
  },

  handleTitleClick: function() {
      this.props.onBlogTitleSelection(this.props.blog);
  }
});

var BlogTitles = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return 
      <ul>
        {this.state.blogs.map}
          <BlogTitle blog={blog} onBlogTitleSelection={this.props.onBlogTitleSelection} />
  }
})

var BlogAdmin = React.createClass({
  selectBlogTitle: function(blog) {
    // act!
  },

  render: function() {
    return 
      <BlogTitles onBlogTitleSelection={this.selectBlogTitle} />
      <BlogContent />
  }
})
```

Comment: This solution is on the right way, but I have to point out binding an element on a function call means you want to bind the click handler on the return value of the function. Which means, onClick handler would trigger at the start of the app and will never get called. I find out a way to pass data through `ref`, in a loop you can specify each single item with `ref=item + blog.id.  https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/expose-component-functions.html

Comment: @klamtlne That's an easy error to make, and I assume that it was simply a mistake in the answer. I've edited the code to correct this.

Comment: @BinaryMuse The simple mistake makes all different, now take a deep look and think how data transfers.